# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'dim_ordering')

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, tf.keras, keras-layer

I've been having some issues trying to make this code work properly, I am getting errors that I'm not sure how to resolve it.

I want to try and practice the code had to develop algorithms to correctly classify cervix types based on cervical images.

This is the model :

```
def create_model(opt_='adamax'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(4, 3, 3, activation='relu', dim_ordering='th', input_shape=(3, 32, 32)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), dim_ordering='th'))
    model.add(Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', dim_ordering='th'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), dim_ordering='th'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(12, activation='tanh'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer=opt_, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 
    return model

def cleanImages():
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=0.3, zoom_range=0.3)
    datagen.fit(train_data)
    return datagen

def fitAndPredict():
    print("cleaning images")
    datagen=cleanImages()
    print("images cleaned")

    model = create_model()
    x_train,x_val_train,y_train,y_val_train = train_test_split(train_data,train_target,test_size=0.4, random_state=17)
    print("fitting data")
    model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(x_train,y_train, batch_size=15, shuffle=True), nb_epoch=200, 
    samples_per_epoch=len(x_train), verbose=1, validation_data=(x_val_train, y_val_train))
    print("data fitted in model")
    test_data = np.load('test1.npy')
    test_id = np.load('test_id1.npy')
    print("creating predictions")
    predictions = model.predict_proba(test_data)
    print("predictions made")
    return predictions, test_id

def createSub():
    pred, test_id=fitAndPredict()
    print("creating submission file")
    df = pd.DataFrame(pred, columns=['Type_1','Type_2','Type_3'])
    df['image_name'] = test_id
     #df.to_csv('submission.csv', index=False)
    df.to_csv(r'D:/Test cods/Sample code1jupyter/csvfile/submission.csv', index=False)
    print("submission created")

if __name__ == '__main__':

    createSub()
```

I couldn't find what is the problem

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
cleaning images
images cleaned
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-83b0d2376a28> in <module>
      1 if __name__ == '__main__':
      2 
----> 3     createSub()
      4 

<ipython-input-66-d63e92615546> in createSub()
      1 def createSub():
----> 2     pred, test_id=fitAndPredict()
      3     print("creating submission file")
      4     df = pd.DataFrame(pred, columns=['Type_1','Type_2','Type_3'])
      5     df['image_name'] = test_id

<ipython-input-65-24f2c91bcb25> in fitAndPredict()
      9     print("images cleaned")
     10 
---> 11     model = create_model()
     12     x_train,x_val_train,y_train,y_val_train = 
train_test_split(train_data,train_target,test_size=0.4, random_state=17)
     13     print("fitting data")

<ipython-input-63-43a9c4acdc14> in create_model(opt_)
      1 def create_model(opt_='adamax'):
      2     model = Sequential()
----> 3     model.add(Convolution2D(4, 3, 3, activation='relu', dim_ordering='th', 
input_shape=(3, 32, 32))) #use input_shape=(3, 64, 64)
      4     model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), dim_ordering='th'))
      5     model.add(Convolution2D(8, 3, 3, activation='relu', dim_ordering='th'))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py in 
__init__(self, filters, kernel_size, strides, padding, data_format, dilation_rate, groups, 
activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, kernel_regularizer, 
bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, bias_constraint, **kwargs)
    654                bias_constraint=None,
    655                **kwargs):
--> 656     super(Conv2D, self).__init__(
    657         rank=2,
    658         filters=filters,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py in 
__init__(self, rank, filters, kernel_size, strides, padding, data_format, dilation_rate, 
groups, activation, use_bias, kernel_initializer, bias_initializer, kernel_regularizer, 
bias_regularizer, activity_regularizer, kernel_constraint, bias_constraint, trainable, name, 
conv_op, **kwargs)
    123                conv_op=None,
    124                **kwargs):
--> 125     super(Conv, self).__init__(
    126         trainable=trainable,
    127         name=name,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\tracking\base.py in 
_method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    520     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    521     try:
--> 522       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    523     finally:
    524       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __init__(self, 
  trainable, name, dtype, dynamic, **kwargs)
    321     }
    322     # Validate optional keyword arguments.
--> 323     generic_utils.validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs)
    324 
    325     # Mutable properties

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py in 
validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs, error_message)
   1132   for kwarg in kwargs:
   1133     if kwarg not in allowed_kwargs:
-> 1134       raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
   1135 
   1136 

TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'dim_ordering')
```

Comment: This is for an old keras version. Replace all `dim_ordering='th'` with `data_format="channels_first"`.

Comment: @Kaveh if it is for old Keras then it should have worked. Like in the newer version there is the parameter `data_format` as you mentioned but there is no `Convolution2D`. The new class is `Conv2D` and hence if he isn't getting a class error he should also not get the current error?

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat `Convolution2D` works, because it is an alias for `Conv2D` in newer versions. Take a look at [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D) and click on "View aliases".

Comment: @Kaveh Got it. Thanks.